# How to dynamically assign a windows message handler?

Tags: delphi, vcl

We can override the handler for a specific message at compile time like this :

```
 procedure WMPaint(var Message: TWMPaint); message WM_PAINT;
```

Is it possible to create a message handler dynamically without declaring the method with the message keyword?

Comment: No it is not. Instead override the WndProc method and handle it there.

Comment: Or use the `WindowProc` property instead of overriding the `WndProc()` method

Answer (score -1):

There is no inbuilt syntax construct to dynamically override a message handler.  There are many ways to achive the same behaviour, however.  As David suggested you could override `WndProc` and handle things there.  Otherwise you could also do something like this :

```
type
  { Return false to call inherited handler }
  TConditionalHandler = reference to function(var msg : TMessage) : boolean;

  TForm1 = class(TForm)   
  private
    FDoOnPaint : TConditionalHandler;
    procedure DoOnPaint(var msg : TMessage); message WM_PAINT;
  end;
```

where (for example)

```
procedure TForm1.DoOnPaint(var msg: TMessage);
begin
  if Assigned(FDoOnPaint) then begin
    { Allow handler to choose if inherited is called... }
    if not FDoOnPaint(msg) then inherited;
  end else
    inherited;
end;
```

Allowing you to attach a handler dynamically

```
if not Assigned(FDoOnPaint) then begin
    FDoOnPaint := function(var msg : TMessage) : boolean
                  begin
                    self.Caption := DateTimeToStr(Now);
                    result := false; { Not actually doing any painting... call inherited }
                  end;
```